# Passing more then 1 value to webmethod using FormData via Ajax

Tags: ajax, asmx, webmethod, form-data

I'm trying to pass the uploaded image + two additional parameters to my web service using the FormData method from my Ajax method as shown here:

```
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', $('#photo')[0].files[0]);
  formData.append('u', "test");
  formData.append('s', "Testing");
```

My ajax call is outlined like so:

```
     $.ajax({
            url: "/admin/WebService/test.asmx/UploadImage",
            type: "POST",
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data: formData,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (er) {
                alert(er);
            }

        });
```

Which calls this webmethod:

```
 [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string UploadImage()
    {

        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.AllKeys.Any())
        {
            var t= System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["s"];
            var c= System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["u"];
            var p = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["file"];
        }
        else
        {
            return "Error";
        }

        return "Error";
    }
```

The issue I'm having is the parameters 'u' and 's' are null yet when referencing file I'm able to get its value.

Whilst searching the web I was under the impression you can specify as many key/values are required when using this approach unless I have been misinformed? can someone please shed some light into why these two parameters are null? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

**JavaScript**

```
var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("UserId", userId);              
            formData.append("RequestPhoto", imageFile);
            formData.append("RequestVoiceRecord", voiceFile);
            formData.append("Latitude", latitude);
            formData.append("Longitude", longtitude);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/User/CreateRequest",
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,

            success: function () {
                alert("OK");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error");
            }

        });
```

**Controller:**

```
 public class UserController : ApiController
    {           

        [HttpPost]
        public int CreateRequest()
        {

            // HttpResponseMessage result = null;
            var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;

            var req = new UserRequest
            {
                UserId = Guid.Parse(httpRequest.Form["UserId"]),                                      
                Photo = httpRequest.Files["RequestPhoto"],
                VoiceRecord = httpRequest.Files["RequestVoiceRecord"]
                Latitude = float.Parse(httpRequest.Form["Latitude"]),
                Longitude = float.Parse(httpRequest.Form["Longitude"]),
            };
```

Comment: Worked for me too, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should create one `json` instead of create this stuff, add whatever keys you want to sent via ajax.

```
var formData  = {'u':'value','s':'value'}

$.ajax({
            url: "/admin/WebService/test.asmx/UploadImage",
            type: "POST",
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data: JDON.Stringify(formData),
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (er) {
                alert(er);
            }

        });
```

try using this way.

Comment: I've changed my code to match what you have specified, however now I'm not setting the keys, how would I go about pulling the values out of formData within the webservice it self?

Comment: are you getting response from service. open console of your browser and check whats it return in response?